# Cannot hit API controller action from AJAX post request

Tags: c#, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

We are moving our server side logic to be called via API's. I cannot get the action to be hit from my AJAX call. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code and why I am getting an error saying it cannot find the action in the controller?

**Controller Action**

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]       
public HttpResponseMessage assignViews(string selectedViews, string volIds)
{
     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

**AJAX Request**

```
self.saveViews = function () {

        var data = {
            selectedViews: self.selectedViews().toString(),
            volIds: populateSelectedVolIds().toString()
        };

        var jsonData = ko.toJSON(data);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../../ja/ClientView/assignViews",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            data: jsonData,
            success: handleViewsForClientSuccess,
            error: handleEditViewsErrors
        });
 };
```

**Routing**

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {           
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            "ja",
            "ja/{controller}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, version = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Comment: [1] Your url should be "../../ja/ClientView" so don't include the assignViews (action name), because it is not part of your routing.

[2] Best practice is to use model instead of strings as parameter. If you use a model, the binding will work correctly. Another option is to use [FromBody]  attribute.

Comment: Taking the action name off did not work. I am going to try creating a model object and setting it as a parameter. Hopefully that will work.

Comment: Creating a model worked like a charm. Please make this an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[1] Remove action name from url**

Don't include the action name in your url, because it is not part of the your routing. The HTTP verb POST will find your action because you marked your action with this VERB and your ajax request is a POST request. Your url should be:

`url: "../../ja/ClientView"`

**[2] Use a model as parameter**

Best practice is to use a model instead of strings as parameter for your action. For example you create this  model in the code:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string selectedViews { get; set; }
    public string volIds { get; set; }
}
```

And change your action like this:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage assignViews(MyModel data)
{
     return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Route registration you've missed to add the Action placeholder whereas you've marked it as "Index" by default which mean your ajax call will try to match with ActionMethod "Index" instead. Trying changing it to

```
ja/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

The other reason could be parameter mismatch.

Comment: "Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:8088/ja/ClientView/assignViews'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller 'ClientView' that matches the request."

Comment: @DeanFriedland - It will be helpful if you can add complete controller code

Comment: Another thing, it may also be because of your parameters are not matching. Trying making a parameterless Action and remove jsonData before verify if your Ajax call hits the Action method.

Comment: Interesting. Let me try removing the parameters to see if I can get it to hit my breakpoint. Good idea...

Comment: Deleting the parameters allowed me to hit the controller action. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @DeanFriedland - I've modified my answer to add this detail. Please mark it as Answer.